# Firebug console window scope. Why isn't "this" always the same?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

Firebug console scope. Why isn't "this" always the same? Shoudn't it be "window" all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `this` in the console will be the same as the value of `this` in the code currently being executed.  Consider:-

```
function outer()
{
        // this is window

    var x = {n:12};

    var fn = function()
    {
               // this is object {n:12}

        alert(this.n);
    }

    fn.call(x);
}
```

...

```
<img src="thing.gif" onclick="outer()" />
```

If you put a break point on the `x = {n:12}` line, switch to console you will find the `this` is the window.  However when you step to the `alert` line `this` in the console is the object held by the `x` variable.   IOW there is no distinction between `this` in the executing context and the console.  Its for this reason that you can use the console to tweak values of variables and properties while debugging.

Comment: thanks for you answer.. but, a question: If I'm not stuck in a breakpoint, can "this" be other than window in the console?

Answer (score 2):

> In a function called directly without
>   an explicit owner object, causes the
>   value of **this** to be the **default
>   object** (window in the browser).
>
> In a function called using the method
>   invocation syntax, like
>   `objname.myFunction()` or
>   `objname['myFunction']()`, causes the
>   value of this to be objname.

See more abot calling functions in JavaScript

[JavaScript, 5 ways to call a function](http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/09/javascript-5-ways-to-call-a-function.aspx)

Comment: This answer accurate as it is doesn't actually address the question as it relates to the console behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The `this` keyword always refers to the owner of the function being called. You can read a clear and detailed explanation on it [here](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html).

From the article I linked above this image I think explains it most clearly:

[image]