# Default scope in Firefox web console - what's going on?

Tags: javascript, firefox, console, scope

In other browsers I've tried (e.g. Chromium, IE, Safari), the default scope of code executed at the console (outside of any function) is the same as that of code executed outside of a function in a `<script>`. That is to say, `this` refers to the `window` object, and any newly declared variables become globals (and, equivalently, properties of the `window` object).

In Firefox... *something else* happens, but I can't quite figure out what. In most browsers, `this === window` evaluates to `true` in the Chrome console, but in Firefox it's false. `this.window === window` is true in Firefox, though. For this reason, variables newly declared or assigned via the console don't become visible to scripts running on the page unless you assign them as attributes of the `window` object explicitly.

The quirkiness doesn't stop there. Assignments made to the `window` object magically propagate up and modify variables in the scope of the Firefox console, but the converse isn't true. Example:

```
window.foo = 5;
console.log(foo); // 5
console.log(this.foo); // 5
console.log(window.foo); // 5
foo = 10;
console.log(foo); // 10
console.log(this.foo); // 10
console.log(window.foo); // 5 -- in any other browser, this would be 10
```

What's going on behind the scenes? What is the mysterious object that `this` refers to in Firefox, and why does it have this peculiar relationship with the `window` object? Is this stuff documented anywhere?

(In case it matters, I experienced this stuff in Firefox 19.0.2. I haven't tested other Firefox versions.)

Comment: Sounds like it's running in another scope. What you're seeing is exactly how prototypical inheritance works. (It appears like you're seeing an object whose prototype is foo). (Related question I just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803660/firebug-console-window-scope-why-isnt-this-always-the-same )

Comment: Try just running `debugger;` in the console.

Comment: I'm on my phone so I can't get the link, but google "kangax delete" and you should get the explanation of this weird behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're experiencing is because the Firefox web console evaluates statements in a sandbox.

[Here is an open bug about it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=690529) in bugzilla

> Expressions entered into the Web Console and the Scratchpad are evaluated in a sandbox global whose prototype is the content window: `this.__proto__ === window`.
>
> This has some nice effects: variables declared in a Scratchpad are effectively local to that scratchpad, instead of polluting content's global; you can play around. If one does want to create a global variable visible to content, one can always simply create a property on window: 'window.newGlobal = "fruit"'.
>
> However, I suspect this is actually not helpful. The simplest mental model for developers is for code entered in the Web Console / Scratchpad to be evaluated just like the contents of their  elements. Explaining why 'x' shows the content's x but 'x = 5' doesn't change it (but 'x.y = 5' *is* visible to content!) involves a degree of detail that only more engaged developers have any interest in.
>
> It's certainly valuable to provide utility functions that aren't present in content; but that can be done by evaluating expressions in the scope of a 'with' expression applied to an object with the utility functions as its properties. 'With' isn't my favorite construct, but since we completely control the object's properties, the shortcomings of 'with' use in general don't apply; once you've decided to introduce some Web Console-only functions, the behavior of 'with' is pretty much what you need. (Don't forget that the following creates bindings for x and y on the global:
>
> ```
> with (o) { var x = 5; y = 6; }
> ```
>
> So 'with' doesn't re-introduce the sandbox problems I mention above.)

About how this works. In JavaScript inheritance is prototypical. What the sandbox is is an object whose *prototype* is window and not window itself. [Here is a tutorial about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_constructor_prototype) in MDN.

Comment: Sweet - not only have you tracked some discussion of this issue online where I had failed, but it's helpful, interesting discussion that explains the behaviour. Thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome. I'd just like to mention that this problem does not exist in firebug. Feel free to browse some of my other answers on SO about prototypical chains